# Apply Grad and Mod to Matrix

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

Let `f:=x^3+y*x*z+z^3;`
Let `mat = {{2, 2, 2}, {3, 1, 7}, {1, 6, 3},{4, 5, 1},{0,4,9}};` be a list of points .

I want to compute the first derivative of `f` at each point of `m` and then apply Mod 4 to each value of derivative.

I have calculated the first derivatives but I do not know how can apply  Mod 4 to the derivatives at each point.

I have tried the following code :

```
grad[x_, y_, z_] = Grad[f, {x, y, z} ]
mat = {{2, 2, 2}, {3, 1, 7}, {1, 6, 3},{4, 5, 1},{0,4,9}}; 
grad[##] & @@@ mat //TableForm
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f = x^3 + y x z + z^3;

grad = Plus @@ Map[D[f, #] &, {x, y, z}]
```

> 3 x^2 + x y + x z + y z + 3 z^2

Or

```
grad = Plus @@ Grad[f, {x, y, z}];
```

Same result

```
vals = Function[{x, y, z}, 
   Evaluate@grad] @@@ {{2, 2, 2}, {3, 1, 7}, {1, 6, 3}, {4, 5, 1}, {0,4, 9}}
```

> {36, 205, 57, 80, 279}

```
Mod[vals, 4]
```

> {0, 1, 1, 0, 3}

Put together:

```
Function[{x, y, z},
  Evaluate@Mod[Plus @@ Grad[f, {x, y, z}], 4]] @@@
    {{2, 2, 2}, {3, 1, 7}, {1, 6, 3}, {4, 5, 1}, {0, 4, 9}}
```

> {0, 1, 1, 0, 3}